# Convert Arrow function to function expression

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a function with a map object:

```js
function xml_encode(s)
{
 return Array.from(s).map(c =>
 {
  var cp = c.codePointAt(0);
  return ((cp > 127) ? '&#' + cp + ';' : c);
 }).join('');
}
```

This has worked great except it has broken everything when running Internet Explorer 11.

I tried to rewrite the code using a function expression however I get a `c` is not defined:

```js
function xml_encode(s)
{
 return Array.from(s).map(function()
 {
  var cp = c.codePointAt(0);
  return ((cp > 127) ? '&#' + cp + ';' : c);
 }).join('');
}
```

Unfortunately this needs to be a public-facing function and I am *required* to support IE11 for now. How do I rewrite this function to work with IE11?

Comment: You left out the parameter: `function(c) ...` — you'll also need [the `Array.from()` polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill)

Comment: or keep ES6 and use a transpiler

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the argument of your function so try this

```js
function xml_encode(s) {
  return Array.from(s).map(function(c) {
    var cp = c.codePointAt(0);
    return ((cp > 127) ? '&#' + cp + ';' : c);
  }).join('');
}
```

Comment: I don't even have to test this, it won't work in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `c` paramter to your anonymous function.

```
function xml_encode(s)
{
  return Array.from(s).map(
    function(c) {
      //use charCodeAt for IE or use a polyfill
      //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt#Polyfill
      var cp = c.codePointAt(0); 
      return ((cp > 127) ? '&#' + cp + ';' : c);
    }
  ).join('');
}
```

Bonus: 
You might want to use `s.split('')` instead of `Array.from(s)` for better performance and **browser support**. `String.prototype.split` is supported in every browser while `Array.from` is not supported in IE for example. `split` is also 30% faster on Chrome and 80% faster on FF on my PC.

Comment: I don't even have to test this, it won't work in IE11.

Comment: True, but thats not what you question was about, I will however see if I can make it work for IE

Comment: Using `split` and a codePointAt polyfill or `charCodeAt` works in IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code as below (you are missing an argument in the function):

```
function xml_encode(s) {
  return Array.from(s).map(function (c) {
    var cp = c.codePointAt(0);
    return cp > 127 ? '&#' + cp + ';' : c;
  }).join('');
}
```

Since, you are using Array.from and codePointAt function, they don't support IE Browser. To use them in the IE browser, we need to add the related popyfill before using this function.

Polyfill code as below (I have created a sample to test it, it works well on my side.):

```
    // Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 6, 22.1.2.1
    if (!Array.from) {
        Array.from = (function () {
            var toStr = Object.prototype.toString;
            var isCallable = function (fn) {
                return typeof fn === 'function' || toStr.call(fn) === '[object Function]';
            };
            var toInteger = function (value) {
                var number = Number(value);
                if (isNaN(number)) { return 0; }
                if (number === 0 || !isFinite(number)) { return number; }
                return (number > 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(number));
            };
            var maxSafeInteger = Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;
            var toLength = function (value) {
                var len = toInteger(value);
                return Math.min(Math.max(len, 0), maxSafeInteger);
            };

            // The length property of the from method is 1.
            return function from(arrayLike/*, mapFn, thisArg */) {
                // 1. Let C be the this value.
                var C = this;

                // 2. Let items be ToObject(arrayLike).
                var items = Object(arrayLike);

                // 3. ReturnIfAbrupt(items).
                if (arrayLike == null) {
                    throw new TypeError('Array.from requires an array-like object - not null or undefined');
                }

                // 4. If mapfn is undefined, then let mapping be false.
                var mapFn = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void undefined;
                var T;
                if (typeof mapFn !== 'undefined') {
                    // 5. else
                    // 5. a If IsCallable(mapfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
                    if (!isCallable(mapFn)) {
                        throw new TypeError('Array.from: when provided, the second argument must be a function');
                    }

                    // 5. b. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
                    if (arguments.length > 2) {
                        T = arguments[2];
                    }
                }

                // 10. Let lenValue be Get(items, "length").
                // 11. Let len be ToLength(lenValue).
                var len = toLength(items.length);

                // 13. If IsConstructor(C) is true, then
                // 13. a. Let A be the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method 
                // of C with an argument list containing the single item len.
                // 14. a. Else, Let A be ArrayCreate(len).
                var A = isCallable(C) ? Object(new C(len)) : new Array(len);

                // 16. Let k be 0.
                var k = 0;
                // 17. Repeat, while k < len… (also steps a - h)
                var kValue;
                while (k < len) {
                    kValue = items[k];
                    if (mapFn) {
                        A[k] = typeof T === 'undefined' ? mapFn(kValue, k) : mapFn.call(T, kValue, k);
                    } else {
                        A[k] = kValue;
                    }
                    k += 1;
                }
                // 18. Let putStatus be Put(A, "length", len, true).
                A.length = len;
                // 20. Return A.
                return A;
            };
        }());
    }

    /*! https://mths.be/codepointat v0.2.0 by @mathias */
    if (!String.prototype.codePointAt) {
        (function () {
            'use strict'; // needed to support `apply`/`call` with `undefined`/`null`
            var defineProperty = (function () {
                // IE 8 only supports `Object.defineProperty` on DOM elements
                try {
                    var object = {};
                    var $defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
                    var result = $defineProperty(object, object, object) && $defineProperty;
                } catch (error) { }
                return result;
            }());
            var codePointAt = function (position) {
                if (this == null) {
                    throw TypeError();
                }
                var string = String(this);
                var size = string.length;
                // `ToInteger`
                var index = position ? Number(position) : 0;
                if (index != index) { // better `isNaN`
                    index = 0;
                }
                // Account for out-of-bounds indices:
                if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
                    return undefined;
                }
                // Get the first code unit
                var first = string.charCodeAt(index);
                var second;
                if ( // check if it’s the start of a surrogate pair
                    first >= 0xD800 && first <= 0xDBFF && // high surrogate
                    size > index + 1 // there is a next code unit
                ) {
                    second = string.charCodeAt(index + 1);
                    if (second >= 0xDC00 && second <= 0xDFFF) { // low surrogate
                        // https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-formulae
                        return (first - 0xD800) * 0x400 + second - 0xDC00 + 0x10000;
                    }
                }
                return first;
            };
            if (defineProperty) {
                defineProperty(String.prototype, 'codePointAt', {
                    'value': codePointAt,
                    'configurable': true,
                    'writable': true
                });
            } else {
                String.prototype.codePointAt = codePointAt;
            }
        }());
    }
```

More detail information, please check the [Array.from() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and the [codePointAt() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt)