# Converting => () => to ES5

Tags: javascript, es5-compatiblity

I'm in the process of converting some scripting from from ES6 to ES5 due to a dependency on the system executing the scripts. I'm running into an issue with this particular command:

```
transition.selectAll('path.hidden-arc')
   .attrTween('d', d => () => middleArcLine(d));
```

I'm not sure what they're trying to accomplish with the '=> () =>' syntax and am unsure how to convert this to ES5 standard functions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on where/how “middleArcLine” is defined. Read up on the difference between “arrow functions” and “anonymous functions”, which should also show to to covert to functionally equivalent forms.

Comment: That's D3. The `attrTween` method requires a factory function that returns another function, an interpolator: https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_attrTween

Comment: Also, that is a function that returns a function. It is equivalent to (d) => (() => middleArcLine(d))

Comment: Related: [Convert Arrow function to function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58081773/1595451)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's using arrow functions to represent a function that returns a function that returns the value from calling the `middleArcline` function. In ES5 it could look something like this:

```js
transition.selectAll('path.hidden-arc').attrTween('d', function (d) {
    return function () {
        return middleArcLine(d);
    };
});
```

Note that [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is a great tool for compiling between different versions of JavaScript

Comment: That was it, thanks! I'll definitely check out Babel.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's a function calling a function. Try this

```
transition.selectAll('path.hidden-arc')
   .attrTween('d', function (d) {
                       return function() {
                           return middleArcLine(d)
                       }
                   }
             );
```

I might be wrong, but just attempting it.

Comment: you missed couple returns

Answer (score 0):

```
transition.selectAll('path.hidden-arc')
   .attrTween('d', function (d) {
                       return function() {
                         return   middleArcLine(d)
                       }
             );
```